# Positioning page sections in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a web development project and am having some trouble getting the elements on my page positioned the way I want them. On my page I have two columns, and two other boxes, one for resources and one for links. I want the columns to appear side-by-side, and the other two boxes to be below them (these boxes will be stacked one on top of the other). As my CSS is written now, the two columns are side-by-side, however, the resources and links boxes are also both beside these two columns.

Here is my CSS:

```
#zen-summary {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    border: 10px double white;
}

#start-id {
    background-color: white;
    color: purple;
    text-align: center;
    width: 400px;
    border: 10px double purple;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

#good-id {
    background-color: white;
    color: purple;
    text-align: center;
    width: 400px;
    border: 10px double purple;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

h3.occasion {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    border: 10px double white;
}

#design-selection {
    list-style-position: inside;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: white;
    border: 10px double red;
}

h3.animals {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    border: 10px double white;
}

#zen-resources {
    list-style-position: inside;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: white;
    color: purple;
    border: 10px double red;
}
```

Here is my html, however the instructions for this project state that I am not allowed to change the html in any way, I'm only allowed to work with the CSS.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>CS 351 - Project 1</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">




</head>



<body id="css-zen-garden">


    <section class="intro-start" id="start-intro-id">
        <header role="bannerRocks">
            <h1>CS 351 Rocks</h1>
            <h2>351 is a really great thing!</h2>
        </header>

        <div class="summaryDivision" id="zen-summary" role="article">
            <p>There are many ways that it is great.<a href="/examples/style.css" title="This page's sample CSS, the file you may modify."></a></p>
        </div>

        <div class="start" id="start-id" role="article">
            <h3>The Road to Enlightenment</h3>
            <p>To be, or not to be: that is the question". - (Act                            III, Scene I).</p>
            <p>"Neither a borrower nor a lender be; For loan oft loses                            both itself and friend, and borrowing dulls the edge                            of husbandry". - (Act I, Scene III).</p>
            <p>"This above all: to thine own self be true". - (Act                            I, Scene III).</p>
            <p>"Though this be madness, yet there is method in 't.".                            - (Act II, Scene II). </p>
            <p>"That it should come to this!". - (Act I, Scene II). </p>
            <p>"There is nothing either good or bad, but thinking                            makes it so". - (Act II, Scene II). </p>
            <p>"What a piece of work is man! how noble in reason!                            how infinite in faculty! in form and moving how express                            and admirable! in action how like an angel! in apprehension                            how like a god! the beauty of the world, the paragon                            of animals! ". - (Act II, Scene II).</p>
            <p>"The lady doth protest too much, methinks". - (Act                            III, Scene II). </p>
            <p>"In my mind's eye". - (Act I, Scene II).</p>
            <p>"A little more than kin, and less than kind". - (Act                            I, Scene II).</p>
            <p>"The play 's the thing wherein I'll catch the conscience                            of the king". - (Act II, Scene II). </p>
            <p>"And it must follow, as the night the day, thou canst                            not then be false to any man". - (Act I, Scene III)."This                            is the very ecstasy of love". - (Act II, Scene I).</p>
            <p>"Brevity is the soul of wit". - (Act II, Scene II).</p>
            <p>"Doubt that the sun doth move, doubt truth to be a                            liar, but never doubt I love". - (Act II, Scene II).</p>
            <p>"Rich gifts wax poor when givers prove unkind". - (Act                            III, Scene I).</p>
            <p>"Do you think I am easier to be played on than a pipe?"                            - (Act III, Scene II).</p>
            <p>"I will speak daggers to her, but use none". - (Act                            III, Scene II).</p>
            <p>"When sorrows come, they come not single spies, but                            in battalions". - (Act IV, Scene V).</p>
        </div>
    </section>

    <div class="bad inbetween" id="good-supporting" role="main">
        <div class="good" id="good-id" role="article">
            <h3>Make it good.</h3>
            <p>"Now is the winter of our discontent". - (Act I, Scene                            I). </p>
            <p>"A horse! a horse! my kingdom for a horse!". - (Act                            V, Scene IV). </p>
            <p>"Conscience is but a word that cowards use, devised                            at first to keep the strong in awe". - (Act V, Scene                            III).</p>
            <p>"So wise so young, they say, do never live long". -                            (Act III, Scene I). </p>
            <p>"Off with his head!" - (Act III, Scene IV). </p>
            <p>"An honest tale speeds best, being plainly told". -                            (Act IV, Scene IV). </p>
            <p>"The king's name is a tower of strength". - (Act V,                            Scene III). </p>
            <p>"The world is grown so bad, that wrens make prey where                            eagles dare not perch". - (Act I, Scene III).</p>
        </div>






    <aside class="sidebar" role="complementary">
        <div class="wrapper">

            <div class="design-selection" id="design-selection">
                <h3 class="occasion">On the occasion...:</h3>
                <nav role="navigation">
                    <ul>
                    <li>
                      <a href="http://cnn.com" class="design-name">Caesar</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://sfasu.edu">SFA</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://cosm.sfasu.edu">COSM</a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>

            <div class="zen-resources" id="zen-resources">
                <h3 class="animals">Resources:</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li class="view-css">
                    Cats</li>
                  <li class="view-css">Dogs</li>
                  <li class="view-css">Elephants</li>
                    <li class="view-css">Rhinos<a href="http://www.mezzoblue.com/zengarden/translations/" title="View translated versions of this page."></a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </aside>


</div>

<!--

    These superfluous divs/spans were originally provided as catch-alls to add extra imagery.
    These days we have full ::before and ::after support, favour using those instead.
    These only remain for historical design compatibility. They might go away one day.

-->
<div class="extra1" role="presentation"></div><div class="extra2" role="presentation"></div><div class="extra3" role="presentation"></div>
<div class="extra4" role="presentation"></div><div class="extra5" role="presentation"></div><div class="extra6" role="presentation"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm pretty sure the only portions of the CSS that I'm concerned with for the present issue are the `#start-id`, `#good-id`, `#design-selection`, and `#zen-resources` sections. I just went ahead and pasted all of it just in case.

I don't have an account on our server for this particular class, so I can't send a link to what the page actually looks like, but hopefully this pic will do.

[image]

I'm sure this is something really simple that I'm missing, this is the first time I've worked with HTML and CSS in a while. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you mind to post your html as well?

Comment: I edited the post to contain the html, sorry I didn't think to do that in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [clear the float](http://webdesign.about.com/od/advancedcss/a/css-clear.htm) between your sets of colums.

Add `clear:left;` or `clear:both;` the the first elemtent you want to appear below the first two columns.

[MDN on floats](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear)

Answer (score 0):

We can wrap the two boxes that aren't behaving with a `<div style="display: table"` to solve that.

Without having HTML to go from I just started from scratch, the following should help you:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/oa460pnj/1/)

HTML:

```
<div>
    <div>a</div>
    <div>b</div>
</div>
<div style="display: table">
    <div>c</div>
    <div>d</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    margin: 1em;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do something similar without changing the html? I forgot to mention in the original post (which I edited to include the html) that we aren't allowed to change the html at all, we're only allowed to work with the CSS.